# Issues installing "pipenv install django" on Mac

Tags: python-3.x, django, macos

So im new to coding and currently tried to learn django i follow this guide from Programming with mosh: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rHux0gMZ3Eg&t=783s
But when i try the pipenv install django it says:
zsh: command not found: pipenv

I have the lastest python 3.11.1 but i can't google any anwsers that worked for me.

Guys please let me know if you could help me out!

I have tried to reinstall pip3 install pipenv.
Googled for solutions this is the best one i found but it still didn't solve the problem:
https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/pip-command-not-found-mac-and-linux-error-solved/

Answer (score 0):

This may be happening because you haven't installed pipenv system-wide (adding it to the PATH). Try reinstalling pipenv with the `sudo` keyword:

```
sudo pip3 install pipenv
```

When you run a command with sudo in zsh it will prompt you to enter your password or pin. When you type it you won't see the characters, that's normal, it's just the equivalent of obscured password characters for the command line.

Comment: Hi @Beikeni
I tried the sudo pip3 install pipenv but it still says zsh: command not found: pipenv

Comment: then try `brew install pipenv`

Comment: still no luck, unfortunately

Comment: zsh: command not found: brew

Comment: then you have to first install brew. Copy this command in your terminal: 

/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"  or google "install homebrew"